# I want to sync data on Firebase (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

The technique I'm using is delete all data related to current user and update its new data.
But the problem I'm facing is it is first calling add data function then all data of current user is deleted including new data. 
My code is.

```
public class AutoSyncService extends IntentService {
    private static DatabaseReference databaseRecord;
    private static FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private static List<FB_Record> fb_records_list;
    private int count=0;
    public AutoSyncService(){
        super("worker_thread");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            databaseRecord= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Record");

        Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

       synchronized (this) {
           Toast.makeText(this, " Data syncronization starded..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


           deleteAllRecords();
           addRecords();

       }



    }




    @Override

    public void onDestroy() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void addRecords(){
        DBSqli info=new DBSqli(this);
        info.open();
        List<String> data=info.getData();
        info.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i += 7) {
            int x = i;
data.get(++x), data.get(++x), data.get(++x), data.get(++x));
            String id = databaseRecord.push().getKey();
            FB_Record fb_record = new FB_Record(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(), data.get(++x), data.get(++x), data.get(++x), data.get(++x), data.get(++x));
            databaseRecord.child(id).setValue(fb_record);
        }

    }


    public void deleteAllRecords(){
        databaseRecord.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot recordSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    FB_Record fb_record = recordSnapshot.getValue(FB_Record.class);
                    if (fb_record.getUserId().equals(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                        recordSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**addListenerForSingleValueEvent** in **deleteAllRecords()** is Asynchronous Listner so calling it before **addRecords** doesn't gaurantee you that it completes the execution of **onDataChange** event before other lines in succession.

Your approach must be that you call the method addRecords(); inside the valueEventListner's **onDataChange** method as given below..

```
public class AutoSyncService extends IntentService {
    private static DatabaseReference databaseRecord;
    private static FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private static List<FB_Record> fb_records_list;
    private int count=0;

    public AutoSyncService(){
        super("worker_thread");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            databaseRecord= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Record");

        Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

       synchronized (this) {
           Toast.makeText(this, " Data syncronization starded..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


           deleteAllRecords();

       }



    }




    @Override

    public void onDestroy() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void addRecords(){
        DBSqli info=new DBSqli(this);
        info.open();
        List<String> data=info.getData();
        info.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i += 7) {
            int x = i;
data.get(++x), data.get(++x), data.get(++x), data.get(++x));
            String id = databaseRecord.push().getKey();
            FB_Record fb_record = new FB_Record(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(), data.get(++x), data.get(++x), data.get(++x), data.get(++x), data.get(++x));
            databaseRecord.child(id).setValue(fb_record);
        }

    }


    public void deleteAllRecords(){
        databaseRecord.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot recordSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    FB_Record fb_record = recordSnapshot.getValue(FB_Record.class);
                    if (fb_record.getUserId().equals(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                        recordSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    }
                }
              // Call to add new records  
              addRecords();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // handle errors here
            }
        });


    }
```